# How to use $this->Html->url in controller CakePHP?

Tags: url, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, router

I'm using ajax to get data from controller. i need to transfer url from controller to view by ajax.

In controller, if i use: `$article['url'] =  '/articles/edit/4bce...';`, when I click, it will redirect to `https://admin-trb-dev-web01.tmh-sd.com/articles/edit/4bce` (404 not found).

That is the page I do not want. The page I want to redirect is: `https://my-trb-dev-web01.tmh-sd.com/articles/edit/4bce...`

So I want to use `$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'WriteArticles','action' => 'edit','tuid' =>'4bce...'))`. It works well on the view, but in the controller, it's not working.

I tried like the code below. But output is not:  `https://my-trb-dev-web01.tmh-sd.com/articles/edit/4bce...` :

```
    $article['url'] =  Router::url(array(
                'controller' => 'WriteArticles',
                'action' => 'edit',
                'tuid' =>  $article['Article']['tuid']).TRUE);
    $article['url'] = str_replace("\\/", "/", $article['url']);
    return json_encode($article);
```

Output:
`url: 'https://admin-trb-dev-web01.tmh-sd.com/articles/edit/4bce..'` :(

Answer (score 0):

> It works well on the view, but in the controller, it's not working.

Because you're violating the principles of a [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework. The layers are separated for a reason.

The controller provides redirect() that does exactly what you want. I highly recommend you to do one of the basic tutorials from the documentation, because I think it is obvious that you haven't read about the basics of the framework: https://book.cakephp.org

[There is also a chapter](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) that describes how to do JSON responses the right way.

Comment: The problem is that I need the url from the controller passing through ajax, I use the full calendar lib, and it? needs that url.